# Proper way to Android update service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I am currently developing Android application with webservice synchronization and everything is working smoothly, but I need to create a background Update service, for data fetching to database. Last couple days, I've been searching for information how to accomplish this and I found many solution, which confused me pretty badly.

I am fetching data using asyncTask which fire up the httpClient and the I parse response and save it to database. After that I send an intent to launch an Activity. Simple stuff.

I want a service, which would fetch the data while the application isn't running. And probably stop the service, when user start the application.

I manage to write a Service class with thread sleep, but this seems like a pretty bad solution.

Another solution I found, is by using pendingIntent and broadcast receivers.

I am not sure if sending broadcast intent is a secure enough. If someone plug his phone into a debugger, he would see every intent broadcast, right? Which means he/she could mess with my application (like send an broadcast intent, which would inform application that new data has been fetch, when in reality, that would not be the case).

I also don't want to getting my service killed by system.

Is there any simple and effective solution for this? I kinda struggle to find something suited for me needs and I am pretty new to Android programing to write it by myself. I found many solution, but I really don't know which one is "right" solution, which is the most effective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [AlarmaManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule periodic tasks. No long running service needed. It just executes the schedule pending intent and finishes after all the execution is complete.

Comment: Many thanks for answer. If you don't mind I have another question. Can I cancel scheduled task, if user choose to refresh data by himself? I don't want to run into situation, when user launch refresh at the same time the scheduled task have refresh scheduled. And with AlarmManager can I launch only service or I could just run the method? I hope, that I don't sound stupid. Because I am really new to all of this. Thanks

Comment: Short answer is Yes. You can cancel schedule tasks. You will have to pass in the exact same intent to the cancel method ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent) ). The alarm manager can start any pending intent, so you basically can fire up any activity, service or broadcast receiver. Here are the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can use Timer:

```
public class ServiceCount extends CountDownTimer
{
    public ServiceCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
    {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish()
    {
        // update data
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        Log.d("timer", "" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }
}

ServiceCount count = new ServiceCount((long) (1 * 60 * 1000), 1000); // 1 minute
count.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, could I run this in background? I mean when application isn't running? That seems like an easy solution, would be nice if this could work like that.

Comment: If you want that this work in background you must use [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). And update what you need.

Comment: Ok, seems like a deal : ) I am going to try that now.